# putting html code from python into html file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

so I have

```
@app.route("/Current.html")
def current():

  recent = api_info.user(user_name="GDcheerios")

  return render_template(
    'Current.html',  # Template file
    recent = recent
  )
```

just as a basic test code.

here is the html file where the variable recent is

```
<body style="background: linear-gradient(0deg, #143827, #266849);">

  <a style="color: black; text-align: center;" href="\">Go back...</a>
  <div class="match">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h2>{{ recent.events }}</h2>
  </div>

</body>
```

it outputs with

TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST

```
[{'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #985 on <a href='/b/192258?m=0'>Itou Kanae - Puzzle (TV Size) [Hard]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 192258, 'beatmapset_id': '63851', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 1, 37, 23, 260000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]
```

I would like to have this html put into the html file automatically with each variable that I call.

Comment: So you want `display_html` only in this case. It looks like `recents.events` is a `list(dict)`. Are there more than one element to this list?

Comment: <img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #985 on <a href='/b/192258?m=0'>Itou Kanae - Puzzle (TV Size) [Hard]</a> (osu!)" so it has extra data after the html, and yeah there is more than one element, these are all the elements "display_html":"htmlcode", 'beatmap_id': 192258, 'beatmapset_id': '63851', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 1, 37, 23, 260000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'

Comment: I can provide an answer later as I would need to test, but you should be able to access that list element and that dictionary much like python syntax. Something like `{{ recent.events[0]['display_html'] | safe }}`. The safe should preserve the HTML syntax and render it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject html into already generated HTML, you can replace the `element.innerHTML` on the JS side.

Comment: well I am not sure if I am getting what your saying but what I tried was using regex to get only the html part out of recent events and keep that as a separate variable, then in html set a js variable for the script.
<script>
      var recent_events = {{ html_finder }}
      document.write(recent_events)
    </script>
    <h2>{{ recent.events }} | {{ html_finder }}</h2>